# Pattern to match any word that does not end with any of letters a,b,c?

Tags: regex

Using Regex.

I have this to find the words that end with those letters:

```
\S+[abc]\b
```

But I need all the words that has these letters in any position but not in the end.

Comment: From the answers I can see there is some ambiguity with your phrase "words that ha[ve] [a,b,c] in any position". Can you give some examples of words that should match and not match to clear up the ambiguity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the ^ character is regex for *not*  (when used in a character group)  so  a slight modification to your regex will produce  :
`\S+[^abc]\b`   :  mach one or more non space characters  and then any character besides a,b or c whose located at the word boundary

Comment: A small addition is necessary to this statement (added part in bold): “the ^ character is regex for _not_ (when used **as the first character** in a character group)”.
`[^a]` and `[a^]` have different meanings. You probably knew that already, right? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If `[abc]` must be somewhere in the word (except the end), you need this:

```
\S*[abc]\S*[^abc]\b
```

If `[abc]` doesn't need to be anywhere, [Alon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207223/alon)'s solution is enough:

```
\S+[^abc]\b
```

Answer (score 0):

a ^ to signify NOT a, b or c should work:

\S+[^abc]\b

Comment: Nope the `\b` takes care of that (word boundary), `$` would be the end of input -- yours wouldn't match words in the middle of the string.

Comment: You're assuming that 'the end' means end of line ($), not 'end of word' (\b), as stated in the OP.

Comment: Thx, figured that out as soon as I hit submit :(